# Rijandeal and special characters

Tags: c#, encryption, diacritics, rijndael

I'm using Rijandeal for enc./dec. and I noticed that some special characters are not correctly managed.

Here is the code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {        
        string enc = RijanENC("šđčćž");
        string dec = RijanDEC(enc);

        Console.WriteLine(dec);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string RijanENC(string texto_puro)
    {
        byte[] key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("123abc12");
        byte[] iv = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
        byte[] stringToEncrypt = System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetBytes(texto_puro);


        Rijndael rjnAlg = Rijndael.Create();
        System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rjnAlg.CreateEncryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cs.Write(stringToEncrypt, 0, stringToEncrypt.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
    }

    private static string RijanDEC(string texto_encriptado)
    {
        byte[] key = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("123abc12");
        byte[] iv = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("0123456789abcdef");
        byte[] stringToDecrypt = new byte[texto_encriptado.Length];


        Rijndael rjnAlg = Rijndael.Create();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, rjnAlg.CreateDecryptor(key, iv), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        stringToDecrypt = Convert.FromBase64String(texto_encriptado);
        cs.Write(stringToDecrypt, 0, stringToDecrypt.Length);
        cs.FlushFinalBlock();

        Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF32;
        return encoding.GetString(ms.ToArray());
    }
```

So the text I want to enc. contains some diacritic characters šđčćž. After decoding i get sdccz instead even if using UTF32.

Comment: There are no special characters, and the question you just wrote proves this. .NET uses UTF16 for strings. ASP.NET renders pages in UTF8 by default. SO uses ASP.NET and stores text in nvarchar fields. That's why you were able to write those characters in your question. In fact, those characters are probably part of the Latin 1 codepage and wouldn't even need Unicode, much less UTF32, in Western Europe

Comment: Why do you think there's any problem with text? What did you try, what was the output and what did you expect? Did you try to *compare* the outputs instead of printing them?

Comment: Good point @PanagiotisKanavos - comparing them would have been a better approach

Comment: The one problem I see in this code is `System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes`. This uses the current locale's codepage which *will* mangle any character not in that codepage.

Comment: Stop using Rijndael which is not a standard and old library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for encrypting/decrypting works as expected, the console output is the problem.

Set the outputEncoding to display the characters in the proper encoding

```
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
Console.WriteLine(dec);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: For the snippet he posted the output is written to the console, and the problem was the encoding, for other outputs I assume the problem to be the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is it. But I'm little bit confused because characters like ç, á, é, â, ü, ö, ä, ß are correctly displayed on console without defining OutputEncoding. Only those characters that I tested at first are not. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Those characters are present in the default encoding's character map ([IBM437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or [IBM850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850)), while the other characters from your initial post are not.